# How to alter/migrate the schema of a table with tons of records

Tags: mysql, migration

I have a table which has about 1 million records, and recently i'm going to ship a new feature which requires 2 new fields. But I found it takes about minutes to get it finish, and during the migration, i have to shutdown the service, as the table was locked.

Is there any ideal way to do such kind of jobs without making the online service offline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this case is:

- create a shadow table with the new schema
- move over all the data
- xlock the original table
- apply the changes since moving the data
- rename the original table to bak
- rename the "new" table to the correct name

This makes your downtime minimal at the cost of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain on this issue and while I do not have an insightful way of speedily adding fields I can tell you what every company I have ever worked for has used as the approach to these sorts of live data problems.

In all cases no matter what other clever tricks we have been using the company will announce a scheduled maintenance window. With the best will in the world the server will need one sooner or later. These windows are usually off-peak and call for some devs to stay late and eat pizza (such a hardship, right). The updates are then run during a down time that users were aware of but unlikely to be bothered by. We would often try and get as much heavy lifting done in the time we had as we could (usually intensive archive and re-index actions and such).

Good communication can turn a server going out into a sense of user excitement at new features that the short pause brings. Thus this is not an irritating loss of service but a moment of transition. It makes the world of difference.

That said it sounds like you have transactional use of the table but it should be possible (I don't know the engine, so I only say should) be possible to carry out a non-exclusive non-locking query. It might take longer but the table would not lock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pt-online-schema-change` tool (free) from Percona? It may solve your locking problem.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Filip De Vos said but with triggers on the old table to keep the shadow copy in sync while data is transferred.

In the past I've used a view to achieve fast switch-over and fail-back from old to new table.  In preparation for go-live rename `DataTable` to `DataTable_old`; create a view `DataTable` which simply `select <all columns> from DataTable_old`.  At go-live re-create this view as `select <all columns> from DataTable_new`.  If acceptance testing fails you can switch back to the previous view with little down time.  The view can be dropped and the new data table renamed at your liesure, or never.  (Sorry, not big on MySQL, not sure how it copes with writing through views).